# Are there limits for session variables in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I will be populating `DataTable` and other `controls` from a complex `object`.

1. Where should I store such an `object`?
2. At what size does session variables starts affecting the performance of page?

Comment: How long do you need to keep the data? Is it for more than one PostBack?

Comment: Do you have many of these complex objects (more the one for each session)? Or maybe just one complex object which can be used throughout the entire application?

Comment: there are different pages and each page relies on one such object

Comment: To my knowledge, session size is only limited by the box (host). The more you're storing in the session (esp. across concurrent users) the faster you'll be using up memory that should be available for other processes. -- Is it unrealistic to re-procure the object on every load? (too much overhead involved?)

Comment: But do you need to keep the data over more than one postback?

Comment: @JohnSaunders yes more than one post back. Till the user closes the page

Comment: Uh, how do you plan to know when the user closes the page?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Just for the sake of curiosity, had it been "only one postback" what would you have proposed?

Comment: The question is actually "during a single request" vs. "during multiple requests". If it was a single request, you could have kept it in `HttpContext.Current.Request.Items`, which is tied to a single request. Multiple requests requires Application or Session or ViewState or something like them.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I don't know yet. The page which will set weekly availability of doctor. The object will store availability and later after changes have been made.. will store it in database.

Comment: You can't depend on knowing when the page closes. Not at all. This is the Web, not a desktop application. I suggest you think about this on the assumption that you will never know when the user is through with the page.

Comment: @JohnSaunders in that case we can just go with default time limit of session variable and prompt a message to the user that the page is about to expire

Comment: Sure. Just remember that there's no relationship between the Session timeout and the Forms Authentication timeout, and neither of those two informs the user, meaning you'll have a client-side timer going (which may or may not synchronize with the other two timers).

Answer (score 4):

Data in the `Session` object is stored in memory on the server.  Thus the storage limit is the memory available to the server.  This data is not sent to the client at any stage, unless you explicitly do so.  Instead the MVC code sends a cookie to the client browser once you have assigned any value to the Session object.  The value of this cookie is then used to uniquely identify the session.

So...

1. The `Session` object is designed specifically so that you can store session-specific data on the server, so is a suitable place for you to put session-specific data structures like you describe.
2. Because the `Session` object is server-side only, using `Session` to store the results of computationally expensive operation that is invariant across multiple page refreshes will speed up page loads, since you can use the previous result instead of having to create it again.  Unless you blow out the memory limits on the server, you're not going to see any performance degradation.

Comment: -1: Session state is not necessarily stored in memory on the server. It can be stored in SQL Server or some other persistent store.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, is not SQL Server is also stored somewhere on the server? Or in other words it is not client solution

Comment: @usefulBee it could be a different server from the web server.

Answer (score 0):

1. If it's a per-session object, the Session dictionary is a reasonable
   place to store it
2. If you are using the InProcess session store, the size of the object never affects page performance (at least until all of the data causes the process to swap).  Other session stores may have a slight impact, based on how long it takes to move the data from e.g. SQL to the local process.  This will be fast until your object gets really big.