# C# read textbox username in homepage from login page

Tags: c#, visual-studio

With Visual Studio how to read username from login.aspx in homepage.aspx in a div?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines and include your code to make a clear and easy to reproduce example.

Comment: if you mean to access username in homepage.aspx after redirecting from loginpage.aspx. you can create a session variable having the username as variable in loginpage.aspx after successful authentication. Session["username"]=txtName.Text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read the UserName of user that has logined successfully. So you can use Session.

ASP.NET session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application

In login page, after the user interd username save it to Session

```
string username = txtbx.Text;
Session["SessionName"] = username;
```

And in every page you can get it

```
string username = Session["SessionName"] .ToString();
```

More information :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: Thank you! But in the homepage string username = Session["username"].ToString(); gives error: "System.NullReferencesException

Comment: My code work correctly for me

Comment: How debug and trace c# application      https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815788

Comment: Let keep question simple.may be your problem is here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382791/what-should-i-do-if-the-current-asp-net-session-is-null

Comment: It's perfect!!! Thank you!!!!

Comment: With Session can i limit the number of the session? How? Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to limit it ? When you are programmer so it depends on how much you use Session.how many data you can save on depending on how many ram of server .for example if you save one byte on session when user logined so if 1000 user is online on your site it gives 1000 * 1 = 1 Kbytes .I think it  is not possible to limitations on number of variables of session

Comment: More information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843237/asp-net-session-size-limitation                   and       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970659/are-there-limits-for-session-variables-in-asp-net

Comment: Excuse me are not explained well. If user login and go to homepage if he copy url and paste in new tab I want that he redirect to login and not access with same username

Comment: I think it is not possible. If user copy url and open same page or all pages of your site , it doesn't related to Session.one session just provide some memory of ram for each user.if user open many pages so why his variables (user name and ...)doesn't copy .so don't worry about it.instead you must study and learn about session